# Unable to open logs - Apache2 on Ubuntu 10.40

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

When I try to restart apache, I get the following:

> - Starting web server apache2
>     (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>     no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs

Comment: Are you trying to start Apache as root?

Comment: Damn, I'm fairly new to linux... Didn't know that the solution is so simple. Thanks!
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have elevated permissions to bind to ports below 1024 and open the apache logs. Switch to a suitable account to restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or similar.